# jquery click event for each class to find href attribute

Tags: jquery

i am new with jquery.
i am trying to find the "href" attribute of targeted element.

I have written a script for click event for each class "link-redirect".In this trying to select href for target element using data-target attribute.

But by using my script i am always getting href of first div i.e "link1".

what wrong i am doing here ?

```
<div class="link-redirect" data-target=".title-link">
    <div cass="div1">
        <a href="link1" class="title-link">LInk</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="link-redirect" data-target=".title-link">
    <div cass="div1">
        <a href="link2" class="title-link">LInk</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="link-redirect" data-target=".title-link">
    <div cass="div1">
        <a href="link3" class="title-link">LInk</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="link-redirect" data-target=".title-link">
    <div cass="div1">
        <a href="link4" class="title-link">LInk</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('.link-redirect').each(function(){
        $(this).on( "click", function() {
            var self = $(this);
            var link = $(self.data('target')).attr('href');           
            alert(link);           
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The class is on the `div`, not the `a`.

Comment: Why data-target element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the anchor element relative(descendant in this case) to the current `link-redirect` element

```
$('.link-redirect').on("click", function () {
    var self = $(this);
    var link = self.find(self.data('target')).attr('href');
    alert(link);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2GfQG/)

Comment: Missed that `data`. You got it.

Comment: @Anup: getting undefined .

Comment: @Kango in that case the html provided by you might be different from what you have in your page... did you check the attached demo

Comment: I got my issue.my html structure slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

You should your `anchor tag` in your `div element` and don't use `each() or loops` to bind `click event` try this,

```
$('.link-redirect').on("click", function (e) {
    var self = $(this);
    var link = self.find('a').attr('href');
    alert(link);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GySpp/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `context` feature provided with Jquery selectors,

```
 $('.link-redirect').click(function(){
      var link = $($(this).data('target') , $(this)).attr('href');           
      alert(link);           
 });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/2GfQG/2/)

Comment: @sarath Sure :) But OP is not asking about that i guess.

Comment: @Kango Did you test the demo provided by me.?

Answer (score 0):

This would be the simplest way:

```
$('.title-link').on("click", function () {
   alert($(this).attr("href"));

});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2GfQG/3/)